# Automake: How to add a building step?

Tags: autotools, automake

Currently, I have a build chain, completly manage by automake, like:

```
.vala > .c > .o > .exe
```

I would like add a new step for preprocess a XML file .ui into a vala source:

```
.ui > .vala > .c > .o > .exe
```

I did this, in makefile.am

```
gtkbuilder2vala_SOURCES = \
    abstract-window.ui \
    main.vala \
    $(NULL)
```

And:

```
XSLTPROC = xsltproc
.ui.vala:
    $(XSLTPROC) ...
```

But make don't understand:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `abstract-window.c', needed by `gtkbuilder2vala-abstract-window.o'.  Stop.
```

This seems to be a limitation of make:

> http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/dev/online/autoconf/autobook/autobook_180.html
>
> if the translation takes three steps--from `.m' to`.x', then from `.x' to`.c', and finally to `.o'---then Automake's simplistic approach will break.

Have you another idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something along these lines

```
BUILT_SOURCES += abstract-window.vala
EXTRA_DIST += abstract-window.ui
gtkbuilder2vala_SOURCES += abstract-window.vala

SUFFIXES = .ui .vala
.ui.vala:
    $(XSLTPROC) ...
```

I would leave the `XSLTPROC` definition to an `AC_SUBST` (or even better, an `AC_ARG_VAR`) in `configure.ac`.